# Is there a way to sequentially execute statements in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

A number of times, I have to write a callback function.

> Example 1:
>   myTransaction.executeSql(stmt,parameters,mySuccess,myError);
>
> Example 2: $.getScript(url [, mySuccess])

Q: Is there a way to tell JavaScript, "Please execute this line of code, and when you're done, execute the next line of code"?

I don't want to lock up the browser session, I just want it to not run the next line until it's done.

Answer (score 5):

Put the call to the second function in the mySuccess handler function for the first function call.  When the first one completes and runs the mySuccess function, that function will then call the second one.  That is the design pattern for sequencing asynchronous operations.

You cannot write normal sequential function calls with asynchronous operations.  You must use the completion functions to do your sequencing.

Here's an example using an anonymous success handler for the first function:

```
myTransaction.executeSql(stmt,parameters,function() {
    $.getScript(url, mySuccess);
}, myError);
```

Comment: +1: but if it needs to e called sequentially, then it needs to happen in both success an error callbacks, otherwise it is branching code

Comment: @MartinJespersen - I leave it to the OP to figure out their error handling as there is no information in the question about what should happen in an error condition in the first function.  If they want it called on error also, then it goes without saying that they have to put it there too.

Answer (score 2):

No there is not a way to exactly what you want. But you can use a library that helps make this less hard, like Step: https://github.com/creationix/step

```
Step(
  function() { myTransaction.executeSql(stmt, parameters, this, myError) },
  function() { $.getScript(url, this); },
  function() { alert('done'); }
);
```

Or you will need to manually nest the callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

The Javascript library [Step](https://github.com/creationix/step/blob/73c55ebc55c13be0b0fa837e083d603dfa691eb6/lib/step.js) provides a framework that encapsulates the solution suggested by @jfriend00.

Answer (score 1):

You can put step 2's call in step 1's success/complete callback, as already mentioned.

Or you can look into the promise/deferred paradigm. It's a little complicated, so I won't try and explain it concisely here (and get it wrong). But given that you already seem to be using jQuery you can probably use its implementation of [the `deferred` object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Here are a couple of articles you can read (though there are plenty more that you'll find with Google):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/09/11/asynchronous-programming-in-javascript-with-promises.aspx

http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

http://www.infoq.com/articles/surviving-asynchronous-programming-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

[Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) is another library, similar to Step, that solves this problem eloquently and provides a host of advantages over setTimeouts or nested callbacks.